# ejabberd muc performance bad

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat

I used Tsung tool to test Ejabberd in Centos(4CPU, 8GB) , and create 3000 users to join a Muc Room, then every users talk in room every thirty seconds,  Centos CPU load more than 3.5, CPU% more than 90%. Less than I expected, Is it Normal Performance? Who can help to answer my question. appreciate

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73822519/is-there-a-way-to-pack-msg-when-using-ejabberd/73825853#73825853

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.